# Is it possible to add a functional field, or perform onchange functions on odoo survey (Qweb views)?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, qweb, odoo-survey

During the survey, I need to add a "functional field", that computes a value based on other fields value.

For example, I have a question (Matrix type), and I want to perform such action during the survey:

[image]

Is it possible to perform such development on a survey?

Comment: mm I don't understand very well. Where are you developping the survey?

Comment: Because I am using it to develop the human ressources appraisals module. The survey here is used as an evaluation form, and I want to do some computation to give the hr manager some hints about goals reaching. I'm available to give you more explainations.

Comment: I'm developing it on survey templates to change the design.

Comment: Ahamm, I think you can make a simple `one2many` field and for the function field you can use something similar to the sale order form. Check where the "Total" is in that form. You can update the value of Total pressing "update" link, but you cannot change its label. Try to copy that functionality. I hope this helps you :)

Comment: The survey template is rendered in qweb templating language, so the tables are generated with html mixed with Python conditions, it's not on xml, so as to create a one2many field. Please check survey/views/survey_templates.xml to figure out what i'm talking about. Thanks for helping.

Comment: mm actually all is rendered with that kind of templates in a low level. But anyway I'm not familiar with the surveys and I cannot help you sorry :(